# spring boot authenticating with custom tables

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm still a beginner in Spring boot coming from a Grails background.

There are already many docs about configuration. But still nothing worked with me until now, I guess it's because i still don't get the whole concept of configuration on spring boot.

I want my application to authenticate using my own database tables.

my current tables are :

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(512) DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `role` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `role_name` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I've tried to configure my security with this class  :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan
public class SecurityConfiguration  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        }

        @Autowired
        public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                    .dataSource(this.dataSource)
                    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.username,r.role_name from role r,users u where u.username = ? and u.role_id = r.id")
                    .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, password FROM users where username = ?")
                    .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        }

}
```

But i still get a 403 when i try to access a page with the correct credentials.

Is there anything missing I should add? do i need to override `userDetailsService`

I can't find any clear documentation that says use the column "users.username" as username, "users.password" as password or a way to override the query of authentication.

Thanks

Comment: Status code 403? That is usually not an authentication problem but caused by some other security conf.

Comment: Please post our logs

Comment: How can i show debug logs containing spring security actions?

Comment: hi, were you able to stick to this schema, I have one just the same (I like user-role approach, instead of authorities) and I am able to log in my site but, just like you, I cannot access, for example, `localhost:8080/admin` even after including `.antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")` in my `configure(HttpSecurity http)` function. please help, thanx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard JDBC implementation of the `UserDetailsService` (`JdbcDaoImpl`) requires tables to *load the password, account status (enabled or disabled) and a list of authorities (roles) for the user*. That schema looks like this:

```
create table users(
    username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null primary key,
    password varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
    enabled boolean not null
);

create table authorities (
    username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
    authority varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
    constraint fk_authorities_users foreign key(username) references users(username)
);
create unique index ix_auth_username on authorities (username,authority);
```

So you should use this for loading users:

```
usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, password, enabled FROM users where username = ?")
```

and this for loading all the authorities for one specific user:

```
select r.role_name from role r,users u where u.username = ? and u.role_id = r.id"
```

And based on `.passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());` your saved passwords in db should be encoded with `BCrypt`. See spring [security doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#user-schema) to gain more insight about how spring security works (not spring boot's one).

**Update:** For enabling HTTP Basic security:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .httpBasic().and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

To authenticate add a `Authorization` header like this:

```
Authorization: Basic <username>:<password>
```

Or you can include the user and password as part of the URL:

```
http://user:passwd@localhost:8080/protected/service
```

Comment: Hi, I made your changes but still didn't work. Still i have too many questions :D. how to know what should be the name of the parameters sent in header for basic authentication ? how to show the DEBUG log for the authentication to know what's happening ?thanks

Comment: You did not enable http basic auth.

Comment: That was it, adding `.httpBasic().and()` made it work thanks

Comment: hello, I have a similar problem like OP, when I try your `select r.role_name from role r,users u where u.username = ? and u.role_id = r.id"` I get ***Column Index out of range, 2 > 1.***, any insights please?

Comment: also, this one does allow me to log in my site: `select role.id, role.name from role inner join user_role on role.id=user_role.role_id inner join user on user.id=user_role.user_id where username=?` but, I cannot access restricted areas like example: `localhost:8080/admin` even after including `.antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")` in my `configure(HttpSecurity http)` function, help please, what would be a proper `authoritiesByUsernameQuery` for a user-role based schema (no authorities if possible)

Answer (score 3):

Three solutions:

1. Create a new class implementing the interface 'UsersDetailsService'
2. You can provide our own 'DaoAuthenticationProvider' instead of the default one to deserialize 'UserDetails' instances for authentication.
3. Redefine constant strings 'DEF_AUTHORITIES_BY_USERNAME_QUERY', 'DEF_GROUP_AUTHORITIES_BY_USERNAME_QUERY' and 'DEF_USERS_BY_USERNAME_QUERY' of 'JdbcDaoImpl' (as shown in the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.html#DEF_USERS_BY_USERNAME_QUERY))